# perl: print to two stdout windows

Tags: perl

We have a perl command line tool that when run prints its output on screen. Now what I want to do is to split the output screen in two halves horizontally. And then some of the information I want to write/display in the upper half of the screen and some in the lower half. Each of these two halves should behave in a normal way, for example they should automatically get a scroll bar if the output exceeds the current display area.
I looked at Cap and Screen modules, they allow you to print at different locations of a window. But I want is to get basically 2 windows, and then write normally to any window I like.
Any perl modules or tips that can help me achieve this behaviour ?

Comment: This is platform/terminal dependent. What platform are you on?

Comment: The platform is Linux

Comment: And are you after an X window, or a terminal?

Comment: OK. Very hard to get a scroll bar on a terminal, because it's something the 'remote thing' is handling, not the bit you have control over. You can move the cursor around to print text though, that's not too hard.

Comment: You could use `GNU screen` http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/ to split the screen and then kick off a socket listener (using `IO::Socket` or something) in the other terminal and send messages to it.